# A new file, git demands a merge, why?

Tags: git, merge, debian, fast-forward

At home I added `do_next.py` and successfully pushed it to the repository. At work I created `cat.py` , made commit and tried to `push` which failed:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I `pull` , the git asks me to merge (to enter a merge comment) .

Please explain why the merge is required? I'd think that since I just added a new file, the `fast-forward` would suffice and no merge is mandatory.

Besides I can't think of a sensible message for this required commit.
Using:
git version 2.1.4
Debian Jessie

Comment: Adding file just avoids the conflict but you have created two tips (one home, one at work). You can rebase one on another and then ff will be possible.

Comment: ... and rebase will be possible with no problem as there is no conflict

Comment: You should have done a `pull` at work, so that work and home were syncronized.

Comment: can you please check the value of your "merge.ff" config value ? `git config --get merge.ff`

Comment: @LeGEC I guess the var is unset, your command outputs nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that git is asking for a merge is because `git pull` is a combination of two commands, `git fetch` and `git merge`.  Since your local branch has a commit that isn't on your remote branch and the remote branch has one that isn't on your local.  You are "ahead and behind".  If you don't want to do a merge, do `git pull --rebase` which will set your local commit aside, update your local branch and then reapply your commit.  Which since you are only adding a new file will work smoothly.

Comment: A clarification on the last sentence; it will work smoothly unless the remote has added a file with the same name and different contents.

Answer (score 0):

In git, a commit refers to a state of the whole repository. You have a commit which contains file "do_next.py", and a commit which contains file "cat.py". Now there should be a commit which contains both of these files, so it just suggests to create it.